# Error installing php mongo driver after php5 upgrade

Tags: mongodb, openssl, debian

I upgraded my php5 version from 5.4 to 5.6 this way (debian 7.9) :

I added

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php56 all
```

to my /etc/apt/source.list file, and then :

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
```

All is running fine :

```
php --version
PHP 5.6.16-1
```

But i need to upgrade my php mongodb driver, and i got the following error :

```
pecl install mongodb 

331 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootmStnQj/mongodb-1.0.0
running: /tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
[...]
checking for pkg-config... no
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/mongodb/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

I have openssl and libssl-dev installed.
Any idea ?

Comment: http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-install-up-mongodb-and-php-on-ubuntu/ try this

Comment: apt-get remove mongodb* --purge did the trick, thanks !!

Answer (score 41):

I had same problem and following command worked for me.

```sh
apt-get install pkg-config
```

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error. I installed the following dependencies before installing mongodb

```
sudo apt-get install -y autoconf g++ make openssl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev pkg-config libsasl2-dev libpcre3-dev
sudo pecl install mongodb
```